# External USB audio interface has weird noises

Tags: 11.10, sound, alsa, soundcard

I have an E-MU tracker pre USB 2.0 connected to a USB hub. It works perfectly in Windows XP on the exact same computer, but has weird noises in Ubuntu 11.10. While being turned on, the system can recognize it and automatically set it as the default output device, but there are some fuzzy noises along with the music playing, no matter in Chrome, or in foobnix player.

I wonder if anybody having an external audio interface experience similar problems? Is it because of the driver? Thanks a lot in advance.

---

Here is more info showing in alsa, noted that E-MU tracker pre supports 44.1khz/48khz playback

~$ **`cat /proc/asound/USB/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params`**

```
access: MMAP_INTERLEAVED

format: S24_3LE

subformat: STD

channels: 2

rate: 44100 (44100/1)

period_size: 44100

buffer_size: 88200
```

In foobnix player, the 44.1khz music won't be resampled to 48khz, while in Chrome the resampling does happen, so I am guessing the weird noise is not caused by resample.

I wonder if anyone using EMU-0202/0404 USB experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: Can you make a recording of the noise, It may be easier to tell what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try running alsamixer in command line and play with the up and down settings. and check if there's no microphone enabled. this should have been a comment but don't have rights to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

**I really don't know.** For my microphone I began to adjust (at alsamixer) all the up and down setting to 0 db gain. I did reduce a lot of noise. I was using Ubuntu 10.04. Finally I tried to test my very cheap microphone with Ubuntu 11 and all the dirty noise where automatically reduced.